# Tips for resizing very wide image for extracting deep-learning model feature-embedding

Tags: opencv, image-processing, deep-learning, computer-vision, resnet

I am using Resnet50 to extract bottleneck features from input image. Resnet or any-other model will always have some input size requirement like: Resnet-50 requires input to be of shape: **224x224x3**.

**Problem**: The input image is of size **5000x90**, which is very wide. Resizing this very wide image into 224x224 has 2 major problems:

1. Information Loss
2. The aspect ratio is skewed, hence directly resizing it to square would not be a very good idea is what I think.

---

**Example**: I cannot put the actual image example but my images look something similar: (posting a random example from google image)
https://pbs.twimg.com/media/D_X0LXRVUAEW8Pg.jpg

My images are similar wide webpage-ads.

---

What I tried:

- Cut the wide image in 7 parts and stack them vertically like: **5000x90** --> **714x90** ..... 7 times --> (stacking every part vertically) **714*630**

Side Note: Since these are ads from web, I felt we can cut it across, let me know if that is even a valid idea.

Please fellow experienced developers, guide me on how to tackle this problem.

Comment: Depends a lot on you application. In the example image, the only object of interest it the car, i wouldn't think you'd need AI to read the text on there. SO maybe try to crop for that. Can you say something about what you are trying to do ?

Comment: Hi, I am trying to detect which brand ad is there on the website. I will be having a database of all the ads which might be present. So I will generate bottleneck features from both the parts, my ads from DB and extracted ads from webpage. Later, will try to perform KNN search.

Comment: you can either use fully convolutional neural networks (which can be applied on any resolution, but it might be hard to find one for classification) or, similar as you are doing, use patches and classify each one individually (dont stack them after cropping, classify separately!). When using patches keep in mind that you might cut the important information into parts, so using overlap between patches can be a good idea. Another idea is to train your model close to the desired aspect ratio.

Comment: Anyways make sure that after resizing to DNN input size, the important information is still present in the images/patches. If the brand logo is only 100 pixels width/height in a 2048x2048 image, it is only ~ 10x10 pixels in a 224x224 image which the DNN works on.

Comment: @Micka, thanks for the patches idea. Will try it out. Apart from that, I can't use any CNN as I am not training anything on my own. First, I will have to try out with already available models.

Comment: if you use any pretrained model you will probably have to use the same kind of image preprocessing (especially stacking of images) that was used during training.